# Haskell - recursion start with the final term

Tags: haskell

Suppose I have the following data structure defined in my haskell code

```
data Exp = Expnum Int - constant
          | Expplus Exp Exp - addition

data Pair = Pnum Int
           | Plus Pair Pair
```

I would like to write a function that can convert the expression to following:

```
-- Example: (Expplus (Expplus (Enum 5) (Enum 5)) Enum 6)
-- equivalent to ((5+5)+6)
convert :: Exp -> Pair
...

-- Expected output: Plus (Pnum 5 (Plus (Pnum 5) (Pnum 6)) 
-- equivalent to (5+(5+6))
```

If here the expected entry is `Plus((Plus (Pnum 5) (Pnum 5)) (Pnum 6)` I will have no problem writing a function like this.

However, I have no idea how can I write a recursion that starts with the final term, while when I parse in the expression it will be `(Expplus (Enum 5) (Enum 5))` that is evaluated first and being returned back

Comment: Don't know if I get your question right but do you know how you'd turn a list of `Int` into a `Pair` with the right *right-assoziative* leaning? Then the answer is to flatten out the input with a traversal and then parsing this back into a `Pair`

Comment: So: you example -> `[5,5,6]` and this into `Plus (Pnum 5 (Plus (Pnum 5) (Pnum 6))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let's fix the definitions (syntax for comment wrong and I want to see the result so `Pair` needs to be in `Show`), and your exampel:

```hs
data Exp = Expnum Int
          | Expplus Exp Exp

data Pair = Pnum Int
           | Plus Pair Pair  
           deriving (Show)

example :: Exp
example = Expplus (Expplus (Expnum 5) (Expnum 5)) (Expnum 6)
```

now the idea is to first *flatten* the `Exp` or if you like to extract the *numbers* in there:

```hs
extractConstants :: Exp -> [Int]
extractConstants (Expnum n) = [n]
extractConstants (Expplus a b) = extractConstants a ++ extractConstants b
```

this yields

```hs
> extractConstants example
[5,5,6]
```

the next step is to build from this list your final `Pair`:

```hs
buildPair :: [Int] -> Pair
buildPair xs = foldr1 Plus $ map Pnum xs
```

so first we add wrap each number in a `Pnum` and then just `foldr1` using `Plus` - you can eta-reduce the `xs` here (see bellow).

note that this is not matching on `[]` - it will not matter but you should not have this on the top-level IMO - we'll fix that later

this one gives for the list the desired result:

```hs
> buildPair [5,5,6]
Plus (Pnum 5) (Plus (Pnum 5) (Pnum 6))
```

so all that is left is to combine those two:

```hs
convert :: Exp -> Pair
convert = buildPair . extractConstants
```

and that's it:

```hs
> convert example
Plus (Pnum 5) (Plus (Pnum 5) (Pnum 6))
```

---

now the issue with the missing case is left - if you think about it it will never happen for a list resulting form `extractConstants` (there can be no empty-list here as there is no way to express this with `Exp`. In this case I'd put at least this helper function as a `where` - here I choose to do both:

```hs
convert :: Exp -> Pair
convert = buildPair . extractConstants
  where
    extractConstants (Expnum n) = [n]
    extractConstants (Expplus a b) = extractConstants a ++ extractConstants b

    buildPair = foldr1 Plus . map Pnum
```